# Want to make my website mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive

I've tried using @media queries, but still, my desktop version is looking like the mobile view.
Is there any way to fix it via bootstrap?

//For mobile view

```
.main-head{
    position:relative ;
}
.home-logo-wrapper{
    height: 20px;
    width: 45px;
    border-width: 1px;
    position:absolute;
}

.home-logo-img{
    width:100px;
    padding:20px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: -80px; 
}
```

//For desktop view

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    *{
        margin:0;
    }
    .main-head{
        position:relative ;
    }
    .home-logo-wrapper{
        height: 20px;
        width: 45px;
        border-width: 1px;
        position:absolute;
    }

    .home-logo-img{
        width:100px;
        padding:20px;
        position: absolute; 
        top: -80px; 
    }
```

I want my desktop versions and mobile versions to be different!

Comment: maybe your mobile view css needs to add `@media only screen and (max-width: 999px)` ?

Comment: have you used bootstrap?
Please share your html also

Comment: Remember min-width means from a viewport width of infinity down to 1000px; not from 0 (mobile) up to 1000px. Use max-width instead to target mobile specific.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is a good option for designing a responsive website. In that grid system is important. You try to understand how to use the grid system for making the website responsive.
The following link will help you to study bootstrap.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Also, sometimes there is a need of media queries either we use bootstrap. Sometimes if we use the font, padding, margin, etc of the same style on all devices view like desktop, tab, mobile it does not look good. So by using media queries, you can code it different style for different devices that look good on all types of devices.

Following media queries will help you for your website.

```
<style>

 /* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {  

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

 }

 /* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {  

  /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

  }

  /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {  

    /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

  } 

 /* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {  

    /* Your CSS Code for this device size */    

 }      

 /* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

   /* Your CSS Code for this device size */ 

 }

 /* According to Mobile Orientation */
 @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {   

    /* Your CSS Code for this device orientation */    

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

desktop view isn't necessarily 1000px and above. i would try changing your media query to min width 320px, and work upwards from there. 
(320px is the width of iphone 5 and SE screens when developing with google chrome developer tools)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    *{
        margin:0;
    }
    .main-head{
        position:relative ;
    }
    .home-logo-wrapper{
        height: 20px;
        width: 45px;
        border-width: 1px;
        position:absolute;
    }

    .home-logo-img{
        width:100px;
        padding:20px;
        position: absolute; 
        top: -80px; 
    }
```

You can also use bootstrap css for responsive design. Which like you asked, kinda 'does it automatically' with some setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //you can write all mobile related css to media less than 767 so use max-width:767px in media for mobile view


    // write desktop related css here



    // for mobile view

    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {        
        .main-head{
            position:relative ;
        }
        .home-logo-wrapper{
            height: 20px;
            width: 45px;
            border-width: 1px;
            position:absolute;
        }

        .home-logo-img{
            width:100px;
            padding:20px;
            position: absolute; 
            top: -80px; 
        }
   }
```

Please Refer below link for more detail:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea using `@media` queries, but the desktop is not by any means 1000px , there is no actual way for you to know the desktop size of other people , you should use queries that cover a range. I use this ones for example:

```css
.my_class{/*it will always be active*/}

/* Small (sm) */
@media (min-width: 640px) { /* it will be active in 640px and bigger*/ }

/* Medium (md) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { /*it  will be active in 768px and bigger */ }

/* Large (lg) */
@media (min-width: 1024px) { /*it  will be active in 1024px and bigger */ }

/* Extra Large (xl) */
@media (min-width: 1280px) { /*it will be active in 1280px and bigger */ }
```

you can also use max width to create a more solid range

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { 
/* it will only be active when the screen is bigger that 576px 
and smaller than 767.98px */ }
```